# Insert a font in the headers.php using child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using child themes in Wordpress for the first time. 
I would like to insert a font in the headers.php, but I want to do it using the child theme.
So far the only file that is on my child theme is the style.css. 
How can I create the headers.php file in my child theme and insert this font:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function wp_enqueue_style instead

make a file and name it `functions.php`

then use this code to include it

> You can replace "My_font" with anything you want, just be sure to avoid spaces, and be sure to replace it in the function "add_action" too.

```
function My_font() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','My_font');
```